# Multiple Webcam WebRTC Videoconferencing App

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to build a WebRTC app that allows a client to stream the video from multiple webcams simultaneously. I'm aware of the MediaStreamTrack.getSources() method to enumerate connected webcams and create video streams for them. Is it as simple as creating a new RTCPeerConnection() for each video stream? Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Many Thanks